# Why doesn't the execution of a function of my contract in a network other than the main network of my contract give an error?

Tags: solidity

I have come across a strange problem. My contract is on the Polygon network, but for example, when I connect to Metamask with the Binance network and run a function of my contract, it is done successfully. while it should throw error or a warning, should it? I should Handle this in the client ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the client should make sure it's connected to the right network. The reason calling a function from your contract on another network doesnt throw is because theres no contract deployed on the other network, and when you send a transaction to an EOA, the calldata is simply ignored. You could deploy an empty contract at the same address (the deployment address of a contract is a function of the deployer address and the nonce, so you can perfectly deploy a contract at the same address on 2 different networks) to prevent this from happening

Answer (score 0):

Yes, must handle it in the client. MetaMask is sending a transaction to an (probably) inexistente account on Binance Smart Chain. MetaMask has no way of knowing that your contract is on Polygon.